# How to Organize Classes in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've come across an issue that I feel has an extremely simple answer but is hard to explain in a short Google search and I can't find anything about this topic.

So, in a recent game I've been working on I have multiple types of objects for every block/tile in the game:

```
    class Char(object):
        ...
        def update(self):
            ...
        def move(self, direction):
            ...
```

or

```
    class Dirt(object):
        ...
```

and obviously, defining all of these classes in the main program can be very *messy*, for example, what if I wanted to create an object in the game that had the name "screen" (a computer screen), well this would conflict with my *screen* class for the actual game window. And, further more, creating a second module called gameObjects also causes the problem that all my game objects don't have access to variables defined in main.

So, how can I organize, or **group**, my classes? I'm a beginner getting into Python, so a simple answer would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: It's `class`, not `Class`. As written, this is going to be `SyntaxError`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You generally don't want to have objects that have the same names as your classes. If they're not defined at the same scope, there isn't actually a conflict, but it's still confusing.

However, if you follow the typical Python naming conventions, this won't be a problem: your classes start with capital letters, and your variables start with lowercase letters. So, your variable is called `screen`, and it doesn't matter that you have a class called `Screen`.

Meanwhile, you do probably want to put related classes together into a module. Objects of classes defined in your `gameObjects` module will not have access to variables defined in main, but you don't want them to. Global variables are almost always a bad idea. If an object needs access to a variable, pass that variable into its constructor.

Before creating your own large project, you should probably look around a few other large projects to see how they organize things.

Comment: The problem is, that it is not a variable screen it is a Screen *class* for the window, not a variable. Are you recommending that I create my "Character" and "Dirt" classes at the same *level* or *scope* as my *main* function and such, I'm not sure it that is considered to be messy or not, it is certainly hard for me to follow though.

Comment: Ah, you're asking whether it's reasonable to have classes named, e.g., `mygame.environment.Screen` representing a computer monitor and `mygame.windowing.Screen` representing a game window? Yes, sometimes that's reasonable. In this particular case, the name really is confusing (a game window should probably be called `Window` or `GameWindow` or something), but I can imagine that, e.g., the in-game viewscreen that the Klingons appear on would be called `Screen`, which would cause the same problem. This is actually one of the reasons that breaking things up into modules is a good idea.

Comment: For the other half of the question: Whether Character and Dirt are in the same scope as the main function really depends on how complex the system is. But I'd guess in your case they do *not* belong in the same scope; they belong in modules that are imported by the main function.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was wondering. One more thing, would it be reasonable to create a class, instead of a module, and use the class not as an instance, but just as you would use a module, or would this be totally unacceptable? Because this would solve the problem of not being able o access variables from *main*.

Comment: You solve this by creating a `namedtuple` of your variables you need in `main` and passing them to the class when you instantiate it.  Organization is key.

Comment: It would be _possible_, but not a good idea. Don't abuse classes as modules. Especially not as a way to solve the problem of accessing global variables—the right way to solve that is to get rid of your global variables and put them in appropriate places with well-defined access chains. Again, the obvious way is to just pass them (or objects that contain them) to any objects that need them in the constructor.